# setEmptyView won't update when listview is changed

Tags: android, listview

I'm using [this horizontal list view](https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView) and if i start with no items in the listView adapter the emptyView shows and also if I start WITH items in the listView adapter it hides the emptyView but my problem is that the empty view will never show if I start with items and remove all the items from the listView adapter and will stay there if I start with no items and try to add items to the listview adapter

Mainactivity

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

      listView = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
      imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, products);
      listView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
      listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty_list_view));
```

...

```
private void loadProduct(Intent data) {

    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    Product p  = (Product)extras.getParcelable(PASSED_PRODUCT);
    imageAdapter.add(p);

}
```

... imageadapter class

```
     public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
```

...

```
public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<Product> products) {
    this.context = context;
    this.products = products;
}

// getView that displays the data at the specified position in the data set.
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // create a new LayoutInflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View gridView;
    gridView = null;
    convertView = null;// avoids recycling of grid view
    if (convertView == null) {

        gridView = new View(context);
        // inflating grid view item
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, null);

        Product p = products.get(position);
```

...

```
        public void add(Product p) {
    products.add(p);
    // notify the list that the underlying model has changed
    System.out.println("product added");
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public void remove(int position) {

    products.remove(position);
    System.out.println("product removed");
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: The code for removing items isn't shown, is it calling notifyDataSetChanged() after removing an item?

Comment: yep, its just the same as the add method except products.remove(p)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to call notifyDataSetChanged() after you remove the data from your ListView Adapter

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have extended `BaseAdapter`, maybe you need to make sure that `Adapter.getCount()` and `BaseAdapter.isEmpty()` are both implemented and returning the values you need.